# Как посчитать большое число в python

Tags: python-3.x

Как с помощью python возвести 4 в 9.6e+22 степень.

Comment: так же, как и в любую другую степень. Непонятно в чем проблема. Тут скорее вопрос - а зачем?

Comment: там похоже слишком большой результат даже для питона .на юпитере результат не получается: памяти нехватает посчитать и крашится. #print(4**960000000000000000000000)

Comment: не думаю, что питон может посчитать число с 57797759167484390000000 цифрами ([`Number of Digits = 1 + b * (log10a)`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-digits-ab/))

Comment: По моим прикидкам, результат будет занимать примерно 22351741790772 гигабайта памяти. Если вы откуда-нибудь добудете столько оперативки — возможно, через какое-нибудь долгое время результат успешно посчитается...